# Assign value based on row remainder

Tags: r

I want to the do the following. I am calculating the remainder of total number of rows in a dataset divided by 20 and based on the remainder (0,1,2,...19) I am assigning a value of x1, x2, x3, etc. to variable called **blf**. For example, if the remainder of the nth row & 20 is 0 then blf = 0.8, if the remainder of the nth row & 20 is 1 then blf=0.7, if the remainder of the nth row and 20 is 2 or 3 then blf=0.6 and so on. When I do it in R **(My code is below and a sample dataset can be found here (both Rdata and csv): http://goo.gl/qgbeIJ)** I get the following error:

> Error in ifelse(sampledat[1:nrow(sampledat)%%20 == 0], 0.8, blf) : 
>    (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'

```
sampledat$blf <- 0.1   
sampledat$blf <- with(sampledat, ifelse(sampledat[1:nrow(sampledat)%%20==0],0.8,blf ))
sampledat$blf <- with(sampledat, ifelse(sampledat[1:nrow(sampledat)%%20==1],0.7,blf ))
sampledat$blf <- with(sampledat, ifelse(sampledat[1:nrow(sampledat)%%20==2] | sampledat[1:nrow(sampledat)%%20==3] ,0.6,blf ))
```

One possible solution is to store the remainders as a separate variable called **remain** and then based on the vector value, do my ifelse operations but I am wondering if there is a way to do it in one step.

```
sampledat$remain <- (1:nrow(sampledat))%%20
sampledat$blf <- 0.1   
sampledat$blf <- with(sampledat, ifelse(remain==0,0.8,blf ))
sampledat$blf <- with(sampledat, ifelse(remain==1,0.7,blf ))
sampledat$blf <- with(sampledat, ifelse(remain==2 | remain==3 ,0.6,blf ))
```

Any insights would be appreciated.

TIA,
Krishnan

Comment: At the very least, if `remain` never exceeds 3, nest your `if-else` and assign all cases which are not 0 or 1 to the final  value. I also don't think you need `with` - just something like `sampledat$blf <- 0.6 + 0.1*(sampledat$remain ==1) + 0.2*(sampledat$remain==0) `

Comment: What happens if the remainder is greater than 3?

Comment: The same process continues with different values assigned to blf based on remainder till 19 and it repeats itself for all records in the data table. For the sake of brevity did not include all the way to remainder = 19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what should happen after a remainder of 3, so I used 0.0.  I did this in a two-step (sort of) easy-to-understand process:

```
answers=c(0.8,0.7,0.6,0.6,0.0,
      0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
      0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
      0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)

sampledata$blf<-answers[(as.numeric(rownames(sampledata))%%20)+1]
```

You can modify the answers array as needed.